# How to disable/remove SMS authentication for a recipient when creating envelope

Tags: java, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

use case: I want to skip sms authentication for a particular recipient using java sdk.

I tried making below changes:
1.
//earlier
xIdCheckConfigurationName : SMS Auth $

//chnages
x.setIdCheckConfigurationName(null);

2. envelopesApi.updateRecipients(docuSignAccountId,envId,recipients);

Answer (score 0):

You can decide for each signer/recipient if they need to authenticate with SMS/phone or not.

Here is a partial Java code, just remember to set `signer1` and `signer2` with everything except the SMS part for `signer1` only.

```
RecipientIdentityInputOption inputOption = new RecipientIdentityInputOption();
inputOption.setName("phone_number_list");
inputOption.setValueType("PhoneNumberList");
inputOption.setPhoneNumberList(List.of(phoneNumber));
    
RecipientIdentityVerification identityVerifcation = new RecipientIdentityVerification();
    
identityVerifcation.setWorkflowId(workFlowId);
identityVerifcation.setInputOptions(List.of(inputOption));

signer1.setIdentityVerification(identityVerifcation);
// signer2 WILL NOT HAVE THIS LINE

Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
recipients.setSigners(List.of(signer1, signer2));
```

Comment: Using this approach you are suggesting to add authentication while creating the envelope. Right? - I tried this approach but I am getting Empty array when I try to retrieve "workflowId". Also I cant find identity verification settings in my admin account.

Comment: And secondly, Currently we have already added these authentication on template level for each recipients, Is there a way we can disable them while creating envelope.

Comment: Yes, you have to modify the envelope before you send it out. If your code creates and sends it in one swoop - change the status from "sent" to "created" or "draft" so that the envelope is not sent out yet, then you modify the recipient by updating it to not include the SMS workflow